# some \newcommand instructions not working

Tags: macros, align

I have  created some new short command using `\newcommand` in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}      
\usepackage{enumerate,amsmath}  

\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}     
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}  

\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}}      
\newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}}  

\newcommand{\bal}{\begin{align}}      
\newcommand{\eal}{\end{align}}  

\newcommand{\bc}{\begin{center}}     
\newcommand{\ec}{\end{center}}  

\newcommand{\de}{^\circ}  

\begin{document}     

\bc      
$5\de$      
\ec  

\ben      
\item Text  
\item Text  
\een  


$\ba{cc}    
a & b\\   
c & d    
\ea$  


\bal      
& r\\      
& f      
\eal  


But   

\begin{align}     
& r\\      
& f     
\end{align}  

is working.     
\end{document}
```

All `\newcommand`s are working well except  `\bal` and `\eal`. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Please format your questions. As is documented you can not use the AMS alignments in that way. You have to use the `\begin` `\end` form.

Comment: My advice is not to do this.  It drastically decreases the readability of your code without saving that many keystrokes.

Comment: Section 6 of `technote.pdf` http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf gives some details regarding this problem.

Comment: To the OP: Please accept answers to the previous questions you have asked. It helps the site run smoothly.

Comment: It's amazing how this question not only keeps coming up, but comes up in *exactly* the notation used in the quote in Matthew's answer.

Comment: @ryan: there is nothing new under the sun. :-) by the same token, for (almost) anything you want to do in LaTeX, someone has already written a package to do it.

Answer (score 17):

David and Ulrike have told you why it doesn't work for `align`.  Quoting from the link Ulrike provided, “[Technical notes on the `amsmath` package](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf)”

> ## 6 Why can't I use abbreviations for `\begin{align} . . . \end{align}`?
>
> ... An attempt to define `\bal`...`\eal` as shorthand for `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}` will fail with a puzzling error message. *This has to do with unfortunately nontrivial technical complications: the given environments must read their contents as a delimited macro argument because they do multipass processing of the contents using algorithms inherited from Spivak's `amstex.tex`*. The obvious solution—substitution of different algorithms that do box shuffling instead of token shuffling for the multipass calculations—would require rewriting these display environments from the ground up; while that is a worthy goal, it was beyond the original scope of the AmS-LaTeX project. [Emph. added]

For my own part, here is why I think in general this is a bad idea, puzzling errors notwithstanding.  Quickly tell me what this code is supposed to produce.

```
\bc  

$5\de$  

\ec  

\ben  

\item Text  

\item Text  

\een
```

If this took you more then 10 seconds you're wasting time.  Now think about posting code looking like that to a forum asking for help troubleshooting it.  Others trying to read it will quickly stumble and not bother.

Compare to:

```
\[
    5^\circ
\]

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Text
   \item Text
\end{enumerate}
```

Much more readable and conventional.

I think that zero-argument, zero-logic macros, unless they add syntactic sugar, represent optimization of the the wrong thing: keystrokes, at a cost of readability and portability.  If you really want to type less, use text-expansion software like [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) or [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: To the OP: Or, use a good editor like emacs which works based on key bindings.