# problem with defining a shortcut for \end{align}

Tags: math-mode

I define `\beq=\begin{align}` and `\eeq=\end{align}`.  `\beq` works correctly, but `\eeq` causes the error

```
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. This is a documented feature of the AMS alignments. You need to use the environment form (which is anyway a good idea for all environments)

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112558/some-newcommand-instructions-not-working

Comment: Actually it is `\beq` that works incorrectly, it reads past the end of the paragraph: `\eeq` isn't executed at all.