# Amsmath environments eating \active characters

Tags: amsmath, catcodes

```
\documentclass{amsart}
{\catcode`\z\active
\global\def\activate{\catcode`\z\active\defz{active}z}}
\begin{document}
{\activate z} %1
\begin{equation}\activate z\end{equation} %2
\begin{align}\activate z\end{align} %3
{\activate\begin{align}z\end{align}} %4
\end{document}
```

(1) and (2) behave as I would expect, printing out 'activeactive' (in a displayed equation, for (2)).  However, (3) prints out 'activez', and I can't figure out why.

EDIT:  (4) also behaves as I would expect, printing out 'active' before the `align`, and then another 'active' inside the `align`.  Is the `align` environment (unlike, say, the `equation` environment) reading its body as an argument?

Comment: ams alignments treat their body as the argument of a command so like any catcode change, your `\activate` or `\verb` etc will not work.

Comment: Oh, as I speculated in my edit.  Do you know why this is done?

Comment: This is documented restriction why you can not define shorthands like `\ba` `\ea`. The body is set twice to do measurement and layout tests.

Comment: Thank you.  Would you be willing to post that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: yes I was just looking if it's a duplicate but nearest seems to be this which is a bit different http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112558/some-newcommand-instructions-not-working

Comment: Can you explain if you have an application in mind or if it's just a theoretical question? Note that, even if the `\activate` problem was solved, you'd need to repeat it in every align cell.

Comment: @egreg, I use a lot of `{align}` environments, and I wanted my `=` to act automatically as alignment points, so I used `\let\equal==\catcode\=\active\def={&{}\equal}` (there should be a backtick in there, but it confuses MathJax).  Doing this once *before* the `{align}` seems to work.  (As I was looking up the restriction DavidCarlisle quoted, I came across the `breqn` package, which looks like it tries to do such trickiness automatically.  Is this package recommended for use?  There are indications in various places that it should be considered experimental.)

Comment: @LSpice breqn is definitely experimental, and incompatible with most things, also if you are wanting things to work in mathjax, no catcode tricks are supported there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks.  My reference to MathJax was literally to it processing my comment above, not to the document that I am trying to write; I don't know how to escape the backtick that appears after `\catcode` so that MathJax doesn't see it.

Comment: I noticed afterwards but that threw me as there is no mathjax on this site:-)

Comment: Oops, right you are.  I should have said Markdown (or whatever the SO flavour of it is called).

Comment: I certainly wouldn't make the alignment on = automatic like this even with the math-active version egreg showed, which is slightly safer, it makes the alignment syntax in your documents incompatible with anyone else, which makes them much harder to process (eg convert to html with text4ht or mathjax etc, and harder to share with other tex documents)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, those points seem to be an argument against using *any* macros in my code.  Also, while I'm sympathetic to the first goal (writing conversion-friendly documents), should "share with other TeX documents" really be a goal?  If I'm not writing a code sample in a package document, then I don't expect others to include my code *literatim* in their documents!

Comment: No if you use `\newcommand\foo{..}...\foo` then that is normal supported use and any system can understand it, if you use low level catcode assignments that change the underlying syntax then typically non-tex systems like mathjax or tex4ht will have problems, and many tex based journal submission requirements would not allow it as if you allow such things you basically lose control over anything the document is doing so it is so much harder for a journal class to force a house style. (actually this particular automatic `&` is fairly benign, but checking it's benign is hard...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMS alignments treat their body as the argument of a command so like any catcode change, your `\activate` or `\verb` etc will not work.

This is documented restriction why you can not define shorthands like `\ba` `\ea` and must use the `\begin` ... `\end` syntax.

The body is set twice to do measurement and layout tests, so the code grabs the body as an argument so that it can be reused.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using active characters, you can use a math active character, which doesn't require changing category code and so avoids the problem due to the fact that `align` loads the contents as the argument to a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathchardef\equal=\mathcode`=

\newenvironment{autoalign}
  {\activateequal\align}
  {\endalign}
\newcommand{\activateequal}{%
  \mathcode`==\string"8000
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`=
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{&\equal}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a     &= b+c \\
a^{2} &= b^{2}+2bc+c^{2}
\end{align}

\begin{autoalign}
a     = b+c \\
a^{2} = b^{2}+2bc+c^{2}
\end{autoalign}

\end{document}
```

In the `autoalign` environment, the `=` character is made math active (mathcode `"8000`) and its active version is defined to be `&\equal`. Then the normal `align` environment is started.

I see no usefulness in this approach, though, but just code obfuscation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Of course it's a matter of taste, but I don't see what's obfuscatory about the latter version.  It definitely favours implicit over explicit, but I don't think that's the same thing.  (Also, if it's any argument, this seems to be a very minor version of the magic worked by `breqn`, so at least there is precedent.)

Comment: Also, is there something missing at the end of the 4th line of your code sample, or is it really supposed to end with the `=` character?

Comment: @LSpice supposed to end that way, it's defining `\equal` to act like `=` that final `=` is a character not part of an assignment syntax.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I see, thanks.  I was incorrectly reading `\mathcardef\equal=` as the complete definition, and the rest as a new command.