# newenvironment: error with \begin{align} and \end{align}

Tags: environments, align

In the example below, an error is caused by `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` but I do not see why:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{subalign}{\begin{subequations}\begin{align}}{\end{align}\end{subequations}}
\begin{document}
\begin{subalign} 
    a&=b\\
    &=b
\end{subalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although @Boris's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236666/1169 works, note that this is *not* a general problem with LaTeX environments, but with `align` in particular (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112558/some-newcommand-instructions-not-working).  For example, if you replaced `align` by `equation`, then your code would work (or, rather, complain about misplaced alignment characters).

Comment: @LSpice yes, I noticed what you describe but I do not know why the `align` environment behaves this way.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112565/1169 (referring to comments of David Carlisle and Ulrike Fischer) quotes the AMS documentation to explain why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is caused by the way `LaTeX` environments are defined.  The simplest way around is to use `\env`...`\endenv` construction instead of `\begin{env}`...`\end{env}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{subalign}{\subequations\align}{\endalign\endsubequations}
\begin{document}
\begin{subalign} 
    a&=b\\
    &=b
\end{subalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you: and would you know how to add an optional label at the `subequations` level? Something like (but it does not work): `\newenvironment{subalign}[1]{\subequations\label{#1}\align}{\endalign\endsubequations}`

Comment: Ok: `\newenvironment{subalign}[1]{` should be replaced by `\newenvironment{subalign}[1][]{` and then it works.

Comment: How can this be adapted to environments with `*`s in their names?  For example, if I wanted to wrap `align*` (obviously not with this example, because it makes no sense with `subequations`)?

Comment: @LSpice I suppose `\csname align*\endcsname` and `\csname endalign*\endcsname` would do the trick

Comment: @AndreasT, I think that doesn't work because `*` is an argument, not part of the name.

Answer (score 7):

Define the environment using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,environ}

\NewEnviron{subalign}{%
  \begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \BODY
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subalign} 
  a &= b \\
    &= b
\end{subalign}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To provide different approaches under same question, this is a `xparse` solution, using the `b`-type argument specifier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{subalign}{b}{%
  \begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    #1
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{subalign} 
  a &= b \\
    &= b
\end{subalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You were missing the end part in the definition (a mistake that I make myself, because of old habits with `environ`). The error went unnoticed because you had an empty line after the definition, but this is taken as `\par` in the end part.