# Modification of some maths environments

Tags: environments, amsmath

I would like to have a minor modification of some standard AMS-environment and realize it as a new one. The problem is that not all the environments allow this procedure. Say, even the mere duplication

```
\newenvironment{myEnv}{\begin{gather}}{\end{gather}}
```

does not work. TeX-system produces the error like

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{gather} on input line 126 ended by \end{myEnv}.
```

However, replacing above `gather` -> `equation` or some other (good) environmens works Ok. I've faced the problem in MiKTeX 2.3 and 2.9. Is this a bug or a feature? Ideally, I would like to construct modifications like

```
\newenvironment{myGather}{\begin{gather} ... my tuning ...}{\end{gather}}
```

Investigation inside the `amsmath.sty` did not help me. Who can? Should I fix a built-in `gather`-environment in this situation?

Comment: The technical notes about amsmath tell you that you need `\newenvironment{myEnv}{\gather}{\endgather}`

Comment: another relevant approach: [newenvironment: error with \begin{align} and \end{align}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236666/579)

Answer (score 3):

In LaTeX, `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` actually call the commands `\foo` and `\endfoo`, so you can try modify them directly if the `\newenviornment` method doesn't work.

With the particular case of the `gather` environment, I believe it changes the way certain characters are handled which I think is the cause of the issue.  This can be solved by preventing `\gather` from being executed with `\expandafter` as follows:

```
\def\mygather{
  \expandafter\gather
    some tuning
}
\def\endmygather{\endgather}
% Or, basically equivalently:
\newenvironment{mygather}{
  \expandafter\gather
    some tuning
}{\endgather}
```

Without knowing what tuning you want to do, I can't really tell you whether that will fix your issue.

Comment: Did I right understand that I may define new environment \mygather by your way above instead of standard one through \newenvironment ... ? I just checked your version. Seems it works nice.

Comment: Yes, the `\newenvironment{foo}` command is just a nicer and more user friendly way of defining `\foo` and `\endfoo`.

Comment: Glad I could help! (PS: don't forget to mark the question as "answered" with the tick.  You should probably do the same with all your other questions too :) )

Comment: Customizations after `\gather` would only act on the first row. And `\expandafter` seems pretty useless.

Comment: @egreg I understand that the customizations after `\gather` would only act on the first row, but @maximav did not really elaborate on what he is trying to do, and apparently it works for him.  Regarding the `\expandafter`, omitting it causes the it to fail, so I'm not really sure what you mean when you say it is useless.

Comment: JP-Ellis. What about environments with the star-version. Actually I wanted not gather but to create a universal alignat* version. Namelly, instead of constant pointing out number of columns in alignat, like

Comment: \begin{alignat*}{3}... I want to have something universal with excessive column number, say, \begin{myAlign*}... written through {alignat*}{22}... I could not modify your way above to the *-case and {22}. How to do this?

Comment: @maximav, without knowing what you want to achieve exactly, it's hard to tell you how the answer should be modified.  As egreg mentioned, my answer would only work for the first row, so I don't even know if that is correct.  Also, of the [questions you have asked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/40791/maximav?tab=questions) you have only accepted one answer... You should consider accepting more answers (though obviously, not this one since it isn't working now).

Comment: Seems I've found a question. Here is a working version \newenvironment{Align*}{\csname alignat*\endcsname{22}}{\csname endalignat*\endcsname}. But there is the question. Is this bad when I insert some excessive {22}? How much bad for TeX-processor to work out, say, 20 excessive columns if I used explicitly only two ones?

Comment: If you use the `\def` method, then you can have `\def\myalign#1{\alignat*{#1}...}`.  In this case, you can then use `\begin{myalign}{2}`.