# Problem in defining new environment

Tags: align, environments, lineno

Since I want to add line number in my manuscript, I have to wrap align environment into linenomath environment to have right numbering. I wanted to define new environment in preamble in which I want Latex to put the math inputting into these environments, but It didn't work. Can you help me please?
Here is my codes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[switch*, displaymath,pagewise, mathlines]{lineno}
\leftlinenumbers
\linenumbers

\newenvironment{Align}{\begin{linenomath*}  \begin{align}}{\end{align}   
\end{linenomath*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Align}
x+y=10
\end{Align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. Should lines of display maths be numbered or not?

Comment: ... "but it didn't work". Please be more specific. E.g., do tell us if you get an error and/or warning messages.

Comment: @Bernard I guess line numbers should be omitted for aligned math.

Comment: @gernot: But that is the default! B.t.w., the `displaymath` is obsolete: it's the default now.

Comment: @Bernard True. Strange. So the purpose remains a mystery, but the problem is solved ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular problem of the `align` environment, see also [newenvironment: error with \begin{align} and \end{align}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236664/110998). In your case, you have to define your environment as

```
\newenvironment{Align}%
  {\linenomathNonumbers\align}%
  {\endalign\endlinenomath}
```

Comment: Yes, but `lineno` doesn't seem to work correctly with `align`: it displays two consecutive numbers (one above the other) for the last line, even if there's only one line.

Comment: @Bernard Well, no harm is done: `\linenomathNonumbers` suppresses line numbers.