# How define new environment in terms of existing environment?

Tags: environments

I want to define a new environment, such as `test` in the example below, whose start and end arguments in turn call the `begin` and `end` of an already-defined environment.

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{test}{\begin{align}}{\end{align}}

\begin{document}

\begin{test*}
a &b
\\
c&d
\end{test*}

\end{document}
```

That produces an error `\begin{align} ... ended by \end{test}`. Is there some way to accomplish this?

What I *really* want is a called inner environment that is more complicated, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newenvironment{\boxedgather*}{\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{\csname gather* \endcsname}}{\end{empheq}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedgather*}
a = b
\\
c = d
\end{boxedgather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: does this answer your question? [newenvironment: error with \begin{align} and \end{align}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236666)  (if it does, perhaps this question should be be considered a duplicate.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes that does answer it completely. Thanks!