# Customize math font (serif, color, etc.) in an environment

Tags: math-mode, color, amsmath, environments, flalign

I'd like to define a math environment that behaves exactly like `flalign*`, except (1) the font is all red, and (2) the math is all rendered as if it were wrapped in `\mathsf`

I've tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\color{red}\begin{flalign*}
}
{\end{flalign*}}

\begin{myenv}
Foo
\end{myenv}
Bar

Baz
\end{document}
```

But this turns everything red after the environment, not just within it. And I don't even know how to set the font for the whole environment.

Is this possible?

Comment: The error is the same as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236664/208544)

Comment: @mbert that does help. Two question: (1) what is the equivalent of \endalign for flalign*? Right now is just does flalign and prints an asterix. (2) How can I make the whole block mathsf?

Comment: You can use egreg's solution below or the, in my opinion, clearer solution with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `b`-type arg in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548724/208544) to the question I linked above

Answer (score 1):

You can't define environments based on `amsmath` alignments that way.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670933/4427 for sans serif math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\newenvironment{coloredflalign}{%
  \color{red!90!blue}\sansmath\csname flalign*\endcsname
}{\endalign}

\begin{document}

\begin{coloredflalign}
A&=B & C&=D & u&=v \\
x&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i & y&=M\otimes N & z&=U^v & x\ne z
\end{coloredflalign}

\begin{flalign*}
A&=B & C&=D & u&=v \\
x&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i & y&=M\otimes N & z&=U^v & x\ne z
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]