# Use mathsf for entire block/environment

Tags: math-mode, fonts, align, math-fonts, sans-serif

Basically, I want to definite a `flalign` environment where all the math uses `mathsf` by default.

I can't just wrap the whole thing in a `mathsf` command because there might be line breaks and & separators that break things.

Is there a version of `mathsf` that works like `\color` where it sets the font style for the entire block, instead of just for the argument?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sansmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath), supplementing it with a sans serif font for large operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\sansmath

\begin{flalign}
A&=B & C&=D & u&=v \\
x&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i & y&=M\otimes N & z&=U^v & x\ne z
\end{flalign}

\unsansmath

\begin{flalign}
A&=B & C&=D & u&=v \\
x&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i & y&=M\otimes N & z&=U^v & x\ne z
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user94293 Yes, of course.

Comment: That looks great, except it makes everything italics in the sans-serif font. Is it possible to disable that?

Comment: @jmite You may want to add `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfsl}{sans}{\sansmathencoding}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}`

Comment: perfect! Two more questions. (1) it seems like right now parentheses symbols aren't being rendered at all, is there a way to fix that? (2) Currently, if I do `\mathrm{...}` inside the `sansmath` environment, it just ignores it and prints it as sans. Is there a way to have sans as the default for the environment, but to still be able to use all the normal font commands in the sans environment?